# Plugins & Setting Menu Items Removed From Admin Panel

Tags: menus, admin

I am unable to add any new plugins and can't see menu settings as well. I think it's been disabled. How do I bring these admin menu items back?

Here's what my admin panel currently looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you don't have an administrative role. Is this a WordPress you manage? Did originally have `Settings` and `Plugins` page then lost them whenever updating something or have you never had access to these two pages on this install?

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.
acctually i have adminstrative role. yes this is wordpress but somebody else design this for me but he said this is the only admin account he made but somehow he removed rest of the menu tabs. i don't know how and he don't want to bring them back for me :(

Comment: please if someone can help me about this :(

Comment: Without knowing how the menu items were removed, it's impossible to help, and without seeing the code, we can't help. Right now this is impossible to answer. I would contact the person who made this for you and ask, they've clearly tried to remove everything that isn't relevant to the theme you're using so it doesn't confuse users

Comment: if you have a look on the 2nd pic , the one i just added, it shows my role

Comment: Where is your site hosted?

Comment: very disappointed with your answer Tom. if i knew that how items were removed, there was no need to ask this question here.

Comment: @MuhammadAtif, the comments so far have been correct, and it doesn't help you to be critical of people trying to help you. Howdy_McGee is correct; your designer has put you in the editor role, not the admin role. If your designer cannot give you admin access, you can hack WP's MySQL database to make yourself an admin account: http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-wordpress-database/ Again, your user account is only in the Editor role, not the Admin role. You need whomever set it up to make you an admin, or create an admin user the hard way.

Comment: hosted on one.com

Comment: ok i appologise :(

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the site, the problem is that the plugin you have that is extending the roles is misconfigured. It says you are in the Admin role, but it has somehow redefined the permissions you actually have. You need to get your designer / whomever installed that thing to properly configure it. Disabling that plugin, by renaming its wp-content/plugins directory, will give you back the default WordPress permissions.

Comment: i think i will have to hack

Comment: but how please? :s

Comment: @MuhammadAtif Go back to your designer and tell him that the Roles plugin he installed has removed your admin privileges. Otherwise, without knowing what plugin he used, all I can say is, use FTP to get into your site, go to the wp-content/plugins folder, and rename every single folder in there. That will disable all plugins, and you can re-authorize each plugin until you discover which one is causing the trouble.

Comment: But if I remove the plugin he has installed something like bb press plugin. What will happen then?

Comment: @MuhammadAtif I can't fix your site for you. You have to take up these problems with your designer.

Comment: There's only one plugin installed brov.

Comment: BB press I think. Let me c

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two step:

1. Try to deactivate all plugins (howto: [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/) and [this](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/));
2. Check if the core of Wordpress hasn't broken. Compare sources in directories wp-admin & wp-includes (it's difficult, but I don't know easy way).